# Correct way to use LIKE '%{$var}%' with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This does not work

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE \'%{?}%\' ';
```

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/rgero/public_html/php/searchadmins.php on line 1

This one doesn't work either

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE %{?}% ';
```

Fatal error: Wrong SQL: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE %{?}% Error: 0 in /home/rgero/public_html/php/searchadmins.php on line 1

How would I go about this? I'm trying to make a search for players function that updates the results as you're typing in the form, something like how google already shows answers while you're typing. I need for the username Admin , if you type dm, to show it already among other usernames that contain "dm". It should also be case insensitive

Comment: You have to pre- and append `%` to the variable you're binding to the `?` parameter.

Comment: Yep, just use `bindParam(1, "%$var%")` etc. and a literal `LIKE ?` in the query.

Comment: So I have to take the variable and add %{ to the beginning and %} to the end?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this

```
$likeVar = "%" . $yourParam . "%";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $likeVar);
$stmt->execute();
```

you need to prepare the query using simply `?` then you bind the param using `bind_param`.