# Using LIKE to find something inside a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I have the following contents in sowner : " 6 4 7 " without the quotes, but with all the spaces including in the beginning and the end. That's the sowner value of a row in the DB.

I have row id which I transform into a string of this form (id is 4) " 4 " then search for it inside sowner to see if it's there. No results returned.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE `sowner` LIKE ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$spacedid = " " . strval($row['id']) . " ";
$stmt->bind_param('s', $spacedid);
$stmt->execute();
$res3 = $stmt->get_result();
```

The purpose is to have an undefined number of people's ids in a string separated by spaces and only showing stuff to people if their id is inside the services sowner field.

I am positive it's the LIKE because if I remove the WHERE, all rows show up.

Also I'm using the same implementation in a on-type search suggestion form like this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE ?
```

Comment: You should fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of things in a string.  You should have a separate table, say `ServicesOwners`, with one row per service and owner.

Comment: Gordon, having an association table like you recommend would make it *possible* for the database to enforce referential integrity, make it *simpler* to add and remove data, and make it *easier* to query. Why would we want to do that? I mean, that kind of takes the fun out of it, debugging the production problem when the list of values becomes longer than the maximum we've allowed for a character string. Doesn't it?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE sowner LIKE CONCAT('%', ?)"`. If you need wildcard at the end, swap the arguments for `CONCAT`.

Comment: Bill Karwin should include a chapter in his book about this.  Oh, wait, he did. Chapter 2. [**SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming**](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1429803464&sr=8-1&keywords=bill+karwin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to use LIKE '%{$var}%' with prepared statements? \[mysqli\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385145/correct-way-to-use-like-var-with-prepared-statements-mysqli)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the wildcard operators to the like

so the statement becomes more like

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE '% 6 %'
```

change the line

```
$spacedid = " " . strval($row['id']) . " ";
```

to

```
$spacedid = "% " . strval($row['id']) . " %";
```

Comment: god damnit I forgot about that, will mark as answer when I can

Comment: @aron9forever please note that storing lists in varchars is a bad practice. see the comments on your question.