# How to using LIKE operator which data saved in variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like, sql-search

I need to search data in the database table.

I save data in a variable, then I want to display the data using it LIKE an operator when the data is called.

This is my code :

```
 $data_input_user = $inFilter;
 $data_input_user = mysql_real_escape_string($inFilter);
 $sqlGetFreq = "SELECT * FROM termfrequency WHERE keyword LIKE 
 CONCAT("%",$inFilter,"%") ";
 $freqResult = mysql_query($sqlGetFreq) or die(mysql_error());
```

Beside that i was trying this sql query

```
$sqlGetFreq = "SELECT keyword, frequency FROM termfrequency WHERE keyword LIKE '%$inFilter%' ";
$freqResult = mysql_query($sqlGetFreq) or die(mysql_error());
```

I was trying that code, but it failed.

Any idea please?

Thanks.

Comment: get rid of those old mysql_ functions, use prepared statements with mysqli.  Then search SO for posts that talk about "prepared statements" and "LIKE"  you WILL find a pre-existing solution on SO.

Comment: okey, i try now using mysqli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to use LIKE '%{$var}%' with prepared statements? \[mysqli\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385145/correct-way-to-use-like-var-with-prepared-statements-mysqli)

Comment: I have tried this syntax 
$variabel_like = "%" . $inFilter . "%";
    //$data_inputan_user = mysql_real_escape_string($inFilter);
    $sqlGetFreq = $variabel_like->prepare("SELECT * FROM termfrequency WHERE kata_kunci LIKE $inFilter");
    $sqlGetFreq->bind_param("s",$inFilter);
    $sqlGetFreq->execute();

but i get error : Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\phpfile.php

Comment: that answer from  Correct way to use LIKE '%{$var}%' with prepared statements? [mysqli] doesn't work in my code

Comment: You must properly connect mysqli and get rid of ALL mysql_ functions.  replace them with mysqli_ functions

Comment: You need to delete this duplicate question, spend some time researching / educating yourself about how to use mysqli and then come back and ask your question after trying to self-solve.  The answer is already on SO.

Comment: Well thanks for advice and advice

Comment: Your accepted solution is bad practice, as I've been trying to tell you the whole time.  I'm trying to help you find the "right way" to do this.

Comment: problem solved use this query : 
problem solved, i use this query :
 $sqlGetFreq = "SELECT * FROM termfrequency WHERE keyword IN ($inFilter) ORDER BY keyword,tittle_symbol";

$freqResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM termfrequency WHERE keyword IN ($inFilter) ORDER BY keyword,titte_symbol ASC") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
   $sqlGetFreq = "SELECT keyword, frequency FROM termfrequency WHERE keyword LIKE '%".$inFilter."%' ";
```

Also please set the following to track any possible error.

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: ok, now nothing error, but when all mysql I replace mysqli data not display

Comment: mysqli_query() takes connection variable as first parameter. You might be missing that. mysqli_query($con,$sql)

Comment: it solved query : 
problem solved, i use this query :
 $sqlGetFreq = "SELECT * FROM termfrequency WHERE keyword IN ($inFilter) ORDER BY keyword,tittle_symbol";

$freqResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM termfrequency WHERE keyword IN ($inFilter) ORDER BY keyword,titte_symbol ASC") or die(mysql_error());