# mysqli bind_param Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

code:

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT name, site, message, `when` FROM messages WHERE message LIKE '%?%'");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['search']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

I'm trying to get the user input into the prepared statement.

This code works fine but is insecure against SQL injections:

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT name, site, message, `when` FROM messages WHERE message LIKE '%" . $_GET['search'] . "%'");
```

Comment: `$par="%" . $_GET['search'] . "%"  ,$stmt->bind_param('s',$par);`

Comment: When you use a parameter placeholder `?`, don't put it inside the string delimiters. A question mark inside a string counts as a normal question mark character. If it were a parameter placeholder, how could you ever use a normal question mark in a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to use LIKE '%{$var}%' with prepared statements? \[mysqli\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385145/correct-way-to-use-like-var-with-prepared-statements-mysqli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `LIKE` in a prepared statement, it's a little bit different. You should add the `%` to the parameter **before** binding it to the statement.

Try something like below:

```
$param = "%{$_GET['search']}%";
$stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT name, site, message, `when` FROM messages WHERE message LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```