# Is this search system vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, search

*I have created a PHP and SQLi based search system. It is very basic and works how all of the ones I have found have. I just have one question. Can a very mean and angry person SQL inject my search system. The search is submitted through an HTML form in POST.*

**Search System Code**

```
...

require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

$search = $_POST['search'];

$mysqli = $conn;

$query = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE listing_name LIKE '%".$search."%'";
echo '<b> <center class="listingstitle">Listings</center> </b> <br> <br>';


if ($result = $mysqli->query($query) and mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $price = $row["listing_price"];
        $name = $row["listing_name"];
        $seller = $row["listing_seller"];
        $picture = $row["listing_picture"];

...
```

Comment: Your code *is* obviously vulnerable. Use a prepared statement rather than concatenating user input in the query string.

Comment: You’re not validating your input, so my guess is “Yes, this query is vulnerable to injection.”

Comment: Yes, this code is extremely vulnerable. See here how to do it properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385145/correct-way-to-use-like-var-with-prepared-statements-mysqli